# Why do we use useeffect() react hook while fetching data by axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch, react-hooks, use-effect

Since the data can be fetched without using `useEffect()` hook, directly from axios, then why it is preferred to use `useEffect()` and then axios?

Also, in which case `useEffect()` is not required?

Here is an example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios
    .get('http://localhost:3001/notes')
    .then(response => {
      setNotes(response.data)
    })
}, [])
```

Comment: What will happen if you remove `useEffect`? try to add a `console.log` inside the response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `useEffect`, you tell React that your component needs to do something after render. React will remember the function you passed, and call it later after performing the DOM updates.
You use React Hooks when using a Functional Component, while using a Class-Based component you can use `axios` in the `componentDidMount()` method to fetch data from the API.

Answer (score 5):

## Without `useEffect()`

Presuming your `setNotes(response.data)` is a state modifying function (second value returned from `useState()`), it triggers a re-render of the component when called.

So when the component gets rendered for the first time, it comes to the fetch call, which on response triggers a re-render of the component. And once re-rendered, again comes back to the same lines of code of your component that makes the call to fetch data using axios, which again calls your `setNotes()` and triggers a re-render... and it keeps on rendering... forever.

You can see it when you `console.log` inside the response.

## With `useEffect()`

By default, effects run after on every completed render (similar to not using a `useEffect()` hook at all), but you can choose to fire it only when certain values have changed, by passing it a second parameter array with the variables.

Passing an empty array as the second parameter causes the effect to be run only once; on the first render of the component.

## When and when not to use `useEffect()`?

Use the hook when you want to do some side effects (data fetching, subscription, DOM manipulation, etc.) on render of a component or when certain values have changed from the last render of the component.

You don't need the `useEffect()` hook when you, for example, have a function to fetch some data on some event (`onClick`, `onSubmit`, etc.), as these won't be run automatically on component render (they're run only on user events).

Comment: I think this is the more accurate answer

Comment: This is the most comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

**useEffect()** calls after the first render and after every update. In your case axios service  will call after render and after every update, you can remove useEffect from your call and put axios in **componentDidMount()**

Answer (score 1):

After React 16.8, I believe the react community is trying to be away from the class. So the hooks concepts were introduced. By using useEffect(), you can avoid using class component's componentDidMount etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you need the component life cycle like `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount` in functional component would use `useEffect` hook